# Unable to write to txt file in php

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-io

I'm trying to simply overwrite a txt file with a number entered in a text box in PHP. Both the PHP and text file are in the html directory of my apache2 server. Every time it executes it just displays the die() string. I also tried using fwrite() with the same results. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<HTML>
<TITLE>Home Automation Interface</TITLE>
<BODY>
    <H1>Air Conditioning Power(Relay 1)</H1>
    <H2>Turn AC On/Off</H2>
    <H3>
        <p> 
            <form action="relayToggle.php" method="get"> 
            <input type="submit" value="AC Power">
            </form>
        </p>
        <form method= "post" action = "homeInter.php">
        <p>
            <label for="acTemp">AC temperature (F):</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="temp" name="temp">
        </p>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="send">Change Temperature</button>
        </form>
        <p><strong>
          <?php

              $temp= $_POST['temp'];
              echo $temp;
              file_put_contents("/var/www/html/temp.txt", (string)$temp) or die("Unable to open file!");
           ?>
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </strong>
            </p>
        </H3>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: what kill the string? the "unable to open"? Then you have to figure out WHY you can't write to that file. it'll almost certainly be a permission issue. And note that your code will run **EVERY** time the form is loaded, whether or not a form was submitted. you probably should test for an actual post before writing an undefined/non-existent value to the file.

Comment: Plus, since you're using this code inside the same file, use `isset()` and/or `!empty()`. You should be getting undefined index notices right off the bat here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: *"Any help would be much appreciated."* - And you have. ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your PHP code Ina valid checker to see if form was submitted

Like this:

```
if ($_POST):
    //All functions go here
endif;
```

If the file is in the same directory as your PHP file just change the directory to the file name.file Extension in your *file_put_content()*